# Which dll version should I use? Razor.DLL - Manifest does not match (0x80131040)

Tags: exception, razor, dll, nancy

Which dll should I be using, and where do I take it from? 
Multiple answers in Stack Overflow explain the problem and the solution of how to correct this error, but none tell me which of the versions is the one I should be using. So here's my question - it will help all those with a similar problem:

I get a

`The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

I have in Visual Studio project after Nuget of the Nancy Razor package a reference to `System.Web.Razor` with version 4.0.30319

Looking in the bin folder I have a System.Web.Razor with a file version of `2.0.20715.0`, I'm not sure the file version has anything to do with the software version...

The Microsoft.AspNet.Razor package version 2.0.30506.0  was installed with the Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor package via Nuget.

Looking under `C:\Windows` I have a whole list of temporary locations for System.Web.Razor.DLL all under `Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319.0\Temporary ASP.NET Files\`  with only one seemingly different version of a System.Web.Razor.DLL file in the directory: `Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Razor\v4_02.0.0.0_31bf....`

Here's my log

```
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\me\Documents\Dev\MyProj\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\me\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/a98e1c21/1e31926/System.Web.Razor.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/a98e1c21/1e31926/System.Web.Razor/System.Web.Razor.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/me/Documents/Dev/MyProj/bin/System.Web.Razor.DLL.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\me\Documents\Dev\MyProj\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\me\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Redirect found in application configuration file: 2.0.0.0 redirected to 3.0.0.0.
LOG: Post-policy reference: System.Web.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/a98e1c21/1e31926/System.Web.Razor.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/a98e1c21/1e31926/System.Web.Razor/System.Web.Razor.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Me/Documents/Dev/MyProj/bin/System.Web.Razor.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Major Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

I tried removing the NUGET cleaning the project, deleting the obj and bin dirs, then re-NUGET of Nancy Razor and rebuild.

My project's reference list properties on the System.Web.Razor.DLL say the dll is to be copied locally.

To no avail.

So I wish to manually set the reference to the correct file. Where is that  correct file?

Or do I have to do something to the GAC? Is it interfering with my IIS Express from VS 2013?

---

Edited Dec 29, 2015:

My web config has the following:

```
  <configSections>
<sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" 
              type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, 
                    System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
                    PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
  <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, 
                    System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, 
                    Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" 
                    requirePermission="false" />
```

The dll files in the temporary directories under v4.0.30319.0 are all copies of the same file. The properties in the References (if I browse to one of those and add to the project's refs, has version number: 3.0.0.0, with runtime version 4.0.30319.0.

When I am in the References.Add-Reference form, it shows me that the file version is: 3.0.20826.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor` only works with V2 / V3 of Razor. You may be able to use V4 with assembly redirects but it is completely untested, we will probably not add support for V4 until Nancy V2 is released.

**Edit:**

I'm not entirely sure how your references got messed up, I actually did all the upgrades to `Nancy.ViewEngine.Razor` references to support V3 of Razor and did too much testing because of strange issues with NuGet pulling the wrong reference. This is the first issue about references raised since I did the PR.

V3 depends on .NET 4.5 so if your project was .NET 4.0 and recently updated to 4.5 then it may have pulled in V2 and not updated it to V3 because the V2 came form the GAC when the dependency was checked.

In theory both V2 and V3 should be coming from NuGet.

To be on the safe side I would remove the references to Razor and Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor, delete the config from the web.config file. Then re-install from Nuget, this should pull from NuGet and pull Razor from NuGet also. Then everything should be properly configured.

Comment: Edited the question. The versions available in the Gac and listed in web.config is 2.  The version I'm now working with, which I referenced manually through "browse..." from a temporary project is 3.

It runs!! 

1. Where is the official version? 
2. Why is this happening, i.e. why did I have to manually select the v3?  3. And should I change what is written in the web.config?  What will happen when I deploy to my real server (not IIS Express via visual studio)?

Please update you answer so I can accept it.

Comment: OK I'll try that. Meanwhile everything is working after i manually selected a System.Web.Razor.DLL file with version 3 at random. In any case I'm marking it as answer.

Comment: I have the exact same issue.  My nancy app uses v3, but when I create a windows service and install the Nancy dependencies into it then it deploys v2 and Razor quits working.